# INTERNAL: platform is already registered with name: "METAL"

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, spacy

I tried to install spacy for python using:

```
pip install spacy
```

This worked, however when trying to get access to the spacy model: "en_core_web_lg" by running the short python program:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
```

I end up getting the error:

```
2023-01-17 11:33:45.771378: F tensorflow/c/experimental/stream_executor/stream_executor.cc:808]
Non-OK-status: stream_executor::MultiPlatformManager::RegisterPlatform( std::move(cplatform)) 
status: INTERNAL: platform is already registered with name: "METAL"
```

I installed tensor-flow a couple of weeks back outside a venv on my Mac running on MacOS Ventura. However I do not know how to "unregister" the metal plugin or reverse the process in a way, that I can use spacy again.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running:

```
python -m pip uninstall tensorflow-metal
```

removed the plugin and deactivated it. From there I could simply paste

```
python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
```

into the command line and the model downloaded